# How to read a CSV file and store the information in a class, when I don't know the order of the columns that will be in the CSV file?

Tags: java, csv, class, class-constructors

I have an assignment, where I need to read a CSV file. I know that the first line of the CSV file will have the following information:

LabelA,LabelB,LabelC,LabelD

and that all of the lines below will have the corresponding information, so all the following lines of the CSV file looks like this:

InfoA,InfoB,InfoC,InfoD

I have created a class that stores all of that information, and then I need to create a HashMap to store all of those objects, each object with the information of a different line, however, the CSV File that I will be reading has a randomized order of the columns, so I might receive a CSV File that has the first line as:

LabelD,LabelA,LabelB,LabelC

Which would make the following lines as:

InfoD,InfoA,InfoB,InfoC

How can I approach this? Regardless of the order of the columns of the CSV file, I need to correctly store that information in an object.

Before this assignment, the order of the columns was always the same, so I was storing each line on a string, then splitting the string, and then putting the information in that order in the constructor of the object, but I can no longer do this, since the order will be randomized.

I am not allowed to use any dependency other than java.io.File, java.util.Scanner, and java.util.HashMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use core java only you can try this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(
                """
                        Col1,Col2
                        aa,bb
                        cc,dd
                        """);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);

        String[] header = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
        Map<String, Integer> mapping = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
            mapping.put(header[i].trim(), i);
        }

        List<MyBean> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String[] data = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
            MyBean value = new MyBean();
            value.setColum1(data[mapping.get("Col1")]);
            value.setColum2(data[mapping.get("Col2")]);
            list.add(value);
        }

        System.out.println(list);
    }

    @Data
    public static class MyBean {
        private String colum1;
        private String colum2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason it never occurred to me to use the setters instead of the constructors, but this should work now, thanks!

Comment: You can use constructor. It won't change much.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using the constructor, I don't know why I was getting super confused on this assignment, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(
                """
                        Col1, Col2
                        aa, bb
                        cc, dd
                        """));
        CsvToBean<MyBean> parser = new CsvToBeanBuilder<MyBean>(csvReader)
                .withType(MyBean.class).build();
        List<MyBean> beans = parser.parse();

        System.out.println(beans);
    }
    
    @Data
    public static class MyBean {
        @CsvBindByName(column = "Col1")
        private String colum1;
        @CsvBindByName(column = "Col2")
        private String colum2;
    }
}
```

Here is required dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Lombock is optional. You can create your bean the way you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use that dependency, sorry about that, I forgot to specify on the question (I am not allowed to use any dependencies other than the Scanner)

Comment: What library you allowed to use?

Comment: Only java.io.File , java.util.Scanner , and java.util.HashMap

Comment: That is harsh. CSV is not as simple as it looks. It will be hard to implement correct parser by yourself. Is it school project? If so, is it allowed to cut corners. Like doesn't support escaping?

Comment: Yes, it is a school project, and I am a little stuck on that. Can you please specify what do you mean by "cut corners" and "escaping"? english is not my native language. I was thinking that maybe I can create a HashMap with the labels as the key and the info as the values, and then I would be able to retrieve the correct index of the labels, but I am still working on that.

Comment: I mean do you need to support `"aaa,bbb",ccc` in your app. This `csv` have only two columns. Value in first column contains separator(`,`).

Comment: In my assignment, that would be considered 3 columns, I don't need to worry about that

Comment: Ok then I'll try to help you.

Comment: Do you think that my approach with the hashMap could work? Storing the label as the key and the corresponding index as the value? I feel like that's the solution but I get very confused when trying to implement it

Comment: Yes. Look at my other answer.